# Touchscreen gets disabled when I put the palm on screen

Tags: touchscreen, stylus

Actually I wanted to write some notes on my 'Android' tablet

**Name: Lenovo Yoga Smart Tab**

**Model: Lenovo YT-X705X**

**Model no. - ZA540019IN**

**Android version: 10**

But I found that whenever I rest my palm in the screen, the screen becomes unresponsive.

So, I did some touch testing and found that the screen isn't registering any touch when I keep the palm rested on the screen.

So basically, when I keep the palm very lightly on the screen, it detects as one giant touch point, but if I keep the palm just like I keep on paper, then the entire screen becomes non-functional.

Please tell me a solution. Is there some option in setting that is turned on or is it not possible to fix this?

Comment: You don't mention what device make/model/OS you are using. Regardless, if you did a search on "touchscreen palm rejection" you would learn that it is a feature of **some** large screen device to avoid accidentally triggering unintended areas. Too large a touch area for a regular device means the touch screen driver designed for fingers is overloaded. At worst, use a mousepad/cardboard/insulator under your hand so that only the capacitive pen/finger is active

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much! Can I answer my own question?

Comment: You can always answer your own question, I would still [update](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/238781/edit) your question to include make/model/OS version in case there is some setting or to at least confirm the lack of a setting for future readers.

Comment: Nothing I have found would indicate that device supports active pen or has capacitive palm rejection. As you have the device, feel free to write an appropriate answer.

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry for replying late but I wanted to ask something related to this. You said that it is a driver problem, so, Can some custom rom fix this issue? I don't know if it is a hardware limitation. Thanks!

Comment: Touchscreens have I believe a hardware defined number of touch points that it can resolve and send data on. Modern phones handle around 5 which is good for pinch-to-zoom with rejection for errant finger/foreign matter on the screen. A palm could be one or several errant touch points which needs to be rejected. If all of the user's hand touch points don't overload the digitizer, a driver/Custom ROM seems possible but I'm not sure of the effort involved for whatever piece of software is doing the rejection. See: http://dirkmittler.homeip.net/blog/archives/tag/palm-rejection for other paths.

Comment: This tablet handles 10 touch points. I tried that app with the "safe zone" feature where it rejects touch input, but I found that when I put my palm on that area, the screen still becomes non functional. So, it seems like it is an OS or hardware limitation.  And I don't think the palm is acting like multiple touch points because when I put my palm lightly it acts as one giant touch point, so maybe the overloading of the touch driver is a more probable reason. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, could you please tell me how the phone determines the size of a touch input? I heard that it has something to do with distortion of electrostatic field of the touchscreen. If that's the case then it seems it is a problem of the controller or something like that. I don't know. Thanks!